# Loading text in Label inside cell UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have defined 3 sections with different numbers of cell on each. It works but when editing the text still there. I tried to clear the content when start typing but didn't work.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
  {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


 UITextField *fdates = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
 fdates.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;   


UITextField *fdeparture= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
fdeparture.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;   

UITextField *farrival = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
farrival.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;   

UITextField *faircraft = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
faircraft.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;   

if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
    fdates.text = fplan.dates;
    fdates.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    fdates.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

    }
}else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    fdeparture.text = fplan.depAirport;
    fdeparture.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    fdeparture.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;  

    }else  {

    farrival.text = fplan.destAirport;
    farrival.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    farrival.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;  

    }
}else {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    faircraft.text = fplan.aircraft_id;
    faircraft.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    faircraft.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
   // faircraft.

}
}

[cell.contentView addSubview:fdates];
[cell.contentView   addSubview:fdeparture];
[cell.contentView addSubview:farrival];
[cell.contentView   addSubview:faircraft];

return cell;
 }
```

To be more clear:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: Try to reload the tableview after editing done

Comment: That is because you are adding the text fields to cell every time even if the cell reuse happens. You should move the `addSubView` calls in the individual `if-else` loops only when the cell gets newly created. Do not add the text fields if cell is getting reused.

Comment: This is common problem. Cells get reused and you end up adding subviews over and over to the cell as it gets reused.

Answer (score 1):

try following code. i have edited your code use this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    UITextField *fdates = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    fdates.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;



    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            fdates.text = fplan.dates;
            fdates.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            fdates.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

        }
    }else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            fdates.text = fplan.depAirport;
            fdates.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            fdates.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

        }else  {

            fdates.text = fplan.destAirport;
            fdates.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            fdates.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

        }
    }else {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

           fdates.text = fplan.aircraft_id;
            fdates.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            fdates.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            // faircraft.

        }
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:fdates];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add on cell not on content view....for more info see below....

```
[cell   addSubview:fdates];
[cell   addSubview:fdeparture];
[cell   addSubview:farrival];
[cell   addSubview:faircraft];
```

Comment: This help a lot, but  –  Amar gave the right answer. Thanks!! working perfectly!!

Comment: @NikosM. This answer is completely wrong and has nothing to do with the problem. Content should be added to the `contentView`, not the cell. But that's not the problem anyway.

Comment: @kate Why did you accept this answer since it did not solve your issue?

Comment: @kate You can't since Amar just posted a comment, not an answer.